# Merge two sorted link lists

Tags: c++, pointers, merge, linked-list

I wanted to merge two sorted link lists by pointer manipulation, but stuck at this point. cant find out the mistake. Help me please. I think the problem is in while loop. I want to make it space efficient and do not want to make another list.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
struct s
{
   int info;
   s *next;
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    char choice = 'y';
    s *ptr1, *ptr2, *start1, *start2, *reversedHead, *temp;
    ptr1= new s;
    start1=ptr1;
    cout<<"SIZE OF A NODE IS "<<sizeof(s)<<" BYTES"<<endl<<endl;
    while(choice=='y')
    {
                  cout<<"Enter info for node: ";
                  cin>>i;
                  ptr1->info = i;
                  cout<<"Do you wish to enter more nodes.? 'y'/'n'"<<endl;
                  cin>>choice;

                  if(choice=='y')
                  {
                                 ptr1->next = new s;
                                 ptr1 = ptr1->next;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      ptr1->next = NULL;
                  }
    }
    choice = 'y';
    ptr2= new s;
    start2=ptr2;
    cout<<"SIZE OF A NODE IS "<<sizeof(s)<<" BYTES"<<endl<<endl;
    while(choice=='y')
    {
                  cout<<"Enter info for node: ";
                  cin>>i;
                  ptr2->info = i;
                  cout<<"Do you wish to enter more nodes.? 'y'/'n'"<<endl;
                  cin>>choice;

                  if(choice=='y')
                  {
                                 ptr2->next = new s;
                                 ptr2 = ptr2->next;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      ptr2->next = NULL;
                  }
    }

    ptr1=start1;
    ptr2=start2;
    while(ptr1->next!=NULL || ptr2->next!=NULL)
    {
                         if(ptr1->info < ptr2->info)
                         {
                                       if(ptr1->next->info < ptr2->info)
                                                           ptr1=ptr1->next;
                                       else
                                       {
                                           ptr2=temp;
                                           ptr2=ptr2->next;
                                           temp->next=ptr1->next;
                                           ptr1->next=temp;
                                       }
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             if(ptr2->next->info < ptr1->info)
                                                 ptr2=ptr2->next;
                             else
                             {
                                 ptr1=temp;
                                 ptr1=ptr1->next;
                                 temp->next=ptr2->next;
                                 ptr2->next=temp;
                             }
                         }
    }
    if(ptr1->next==NULL)
                    ptr1->next=ptr2;
    else
        ptr2->next=ptr1;
    cout<<"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";                    
    if(start1->info>start2->info)
    {
                             ptr2=start2;
                             while(ptr2!=NULL){
                                              cout<<ptr2->info<<"\t";
                                              ptr2=ptr2->next;}
    } 
    else
    {
                             ptr1=start1;
                             while(ptr1!=NULL){
                                              cout<<ptr1->info<<"\t";
                                              ptr1=ptr1->next;}
    }          



    getch();
}
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Did you try debugging?

Comment: It would help if you supplied the input you've tried in your application, the output you got and the output you expected. Also, is there any particular reason you are not using `std::list`?

Comment: If you are just trying to have code that works, use `std::list` and then use method `std::list::merge()`; fast and simple. If you have another reason for doing this (learning, for example), you will have more specific than just *it doesn't work*.

Comment: INPUTS-> 3,5 in first list, 4,6 in second list.
OUTPUT(expected)->3,4,5,6
But execution just ends abruptly.

Comment: i didnt use std::list::merge() because i had to learn about merging and pointers.

Comment: The thing i want to do is that the lists should merge in a way such that if on list contains 3 and 5, and second one has 4 and 6, then if 4 is encountered from the second list....it should be inserted in the first list between 3 and 5. and hence the output should result as 3->4->5->6->NULL (without using any extra node memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while loop condition is not quite right.

```
while(ptr1->next!=NULL || ptr2->next!=NULL)
```

is fine, but *only when both lists are the same length*!. When the lists are of different lengths, either `ptr1->next` or `ptr2->next` will be `NULL`, and you'll get a segmentation fault. Changing to to `&&` is not the correct thing to do, because you'll lose the end of one of your lists!

Use this:

```
while((ptr1 != NULL && ptr2 != NULL) && (ptr1->next!=NULL || ptr2->next!=NULL))
```

Now, inside your loop you have tests like this:

```
if(ptr1->next->info < ptr2->info)
```

replace this with

```
if(ptr1 != NULL && ptr1->next->info < ptr2->info)
```

so that unequal length lists don't terminate early and don't segfault inside.

Next, inside your insert operations, you do things like

```
ptr1=temp;
ptr1=ptr1->next
```

and

```
ptr2=temp;
ptr2=ptr2->next;
```

This is bad, because `temp` is undefined as you never write any valid data to it! The bug here is that your assignments are the wrong way round. You should have done `temp=ptr1` and `temp=ptr2` respectively.

Finally, your cleanup operation to fix up equal length input lists needs to account for the fact that unequal length input lists can result in either `ptr1` or `ptr2` being `NULL`:

```
if(ptr1 != NULL && ptr1->next==NULL)
    ptr1->next=ptr2;
else if (ptr2 != NULL)
    ptr2->next=ptr1;
```

And all seems to be well. I've tested the resulting code on `1 3 5`,`2 4 6` and `1 3`,`2` and `1 4`,`2 3` and `1 3`,`2 3` and all work as I'd expect them to.

Comment: Shit. How could i not notice such a blunder. thanks @rook. :) :p

Comment: FIRST LIST-> 3,5
SECOND LIST-> 4,6
Now the output is coming 3->4->5 (not 6) :( :(

Comment: Thanku. :) help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Did not check it all but lets start here :

```
 while(ptr1->next!=NULL || ptr2->next!=NULL)
```

It should be `&&` and not `||` since you do not want to continue comparing when the next entry in one of the lists is null (you do use its contents in one of the ifs in the while loop)

Comment: I'll advice you to use a debugger and also look at @Rook's answer